# Find root of implicit function in MATLAB 

Tags: function, matlab, root, implicit

I have an implicit function, for example:

```
f(x,y) = x.^3 + x.*y + y.^2 - 36
```

I want to solve the root. `So f(x,y) = 0`.

Drawing the solution is easy:

```
ezplot('x.^3 + x.*y + y.^2 - 36',[-10 10 -10 10]);
```

However, I would like to have the data that is in the plot and not only the visual plot. 
So how do I find the data of the plot? i.e., how to get data OUT of a plot once it is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply an output argument to `ezplot`, it will give you a [line handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/line_props.html). One of the properties of line handles is `XData` and `YData`. To extract data from the line handles, use [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/get.html):

```
LH = ezplot('x.^3 + x.*y + y.^2 - 36',[-10 10 -10 10]);
XData = get(LH, 'XData');
YData = get(LH, 'YData');
```